# In Java, how would I code a pyramid of asterisks by using nested for loops?

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I am working on an assignment where I have to use nested loops to program a pyramid of asterisks that is on its side.
The output of this program should look like this:

```
*    
**    
***    
**** 
***
**
*
```

When I run my program, it only displays the final four lines of the code. I don't know why the first three don't show up.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++) //1
        {
            if(a < 4){
                for(int b = a; b < 4; b++)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

            }
            if(a >= 4)
                for(int c = a; c < 4; c++)
                {  
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

            System.out.println();
        } //loop 1

    }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
****
***
**
*
```

(There is some empty space after the output that I did not include. This is caused by the outer for loop iterating eight times.) How would I make my program correctly display all of the code, instead of just the last four lines?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way to do this would be to count the asterisks on each line for the correct case.  Then print out on each line the number of asterisks that you think need to be printed before you print them.  I think those calculations are off.

Comment: `for(int c = a; c < 4; c++)`: think about what value `a` has when you start this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your logic:

1. Since you only need 7 `rows`, the first loop should iterate until `a < 7`
2. In the first 3 rows, your `nested loop` should iterate from `0` to `a`
3. After that, the other `nested loop` should go from `a` to `7`
4. It is better to use `if-else` instead of two `if` statements

Here is the complete solution that I tested:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
     if(a < 4){
          for(int b = 0; b <= a; b++)
               System.out.print("*");
     }else {
          for(int c = a; c < 7; c++)
               System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, you can also split the outer loop into two parts in order to remove the conditions as follows:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
     for(int b = 0; b <= a; b++)
          System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println();
}
for(int a = 4; a <= 7; a++) {
     for(int b = a; b < 7; b++)
          System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the inner conditional: split the outer loop into two loops, from [0..4), then [4..7).

Comment: Yes, but I remember that such exercises are assigned to teach the concept of ``nested loops``

Comment: You'd still have nested loops.

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand the errors I made in my logic. I also now see that the inner for loops should go inside of the if statements--not the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the suggestion! I edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Try something like this:

```
int size = 4;

for(int line = 1; line < size * 2; line++) {
  if(line <= size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
  }
  else {
    for(int i = 0; i < size * 2 - line; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```